# Creation of additional commands for Alexa Smart Home Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

For my project is ideally suited Smart Home Skill from Amazon. Tell me please, can I add additional commands (eg turn left, close door, show last video etc.) or only commands which are presented on this page [(link)](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201751280) is available to me?

I have in the lambda function my commands but Alexa only recognizes standard. I have studied the documentation, but I did not find the information about how to Smart Home Skill, can add additional commands. But also I didn't find the information that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the Smart Home Skill, only the designated actions are available.

To create an expanded feature set, create a custom skill.  It will require the user to use the skill name (e.g. Alexa, ask my service to turn left) as part of the activation.

Note, depending on your use case, you could do both to cover all needs.

**Update triggered from comment:**

With this approach, you are building two skills.  A Smart Home skill and traditional Alexa Skill.  They will each have their own entry points into your code.  The Smart Home Skill is usually a subset of features in your Alexa skill.

The Home Skill requires implementation as an AWS Lambda, so it would probably be easier to build the ASK front end for both skills in AWS.  My solution started as an ASK skill prior to the availability of the Home Skill so my architecture is different.

For me, I route all Home skill requests through the AWS Lambda (mostly just the sample shell code) and then to my hosted service that performs the actual function and builds the appropriate ASK response.  So, the Lambda logic is mostly just a proxy/wrapper for my code hosted elsewhere.

Comment: And could you tell me a few words, how it can be implemented. Actually, I want to bind user's Alexa account with his device. And send via AWS Lyabmda command to the server, and that in turn redirect command to the device. I'm sorry I bothered you. But Amazon documentation disgusting.

Comment: @Jim Rush How are you discovering a user's device with the custom skill? Let say user had configures them in Alexa App, how to retrieve those?

Comment: My skill links into my own person HA environment that knows about all of my devices.  The skill is just there to create a voice control interface.

Answer (score 0):

The number of "directives" available through the Smart Home Skill API is regularly increasing. At this time only Amazon can create new directives, but, as noted this list is growing.

Three weeks ago Amazon completely revamped the developer documentation for the Alexa Smart Home Skill API (and added new directives). You can find the updated landing pages with overview info here:

https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/smart-home/build

Updated reference material is here:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/smart-home-skill-api-message-reference.html